# Represent $\sin x^6$ in $\sin(nx)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How do you represent $\sin x^6$ in $\sin(nx)$? I've already converted it into $\frac{1}{64(2i \sin(x))^6}$ and put it in terms $\cos(nx)$, but I can't find it in terms of $\sin(nx)$

Comment: actually, the resulting function is even as if $f(x) = f(-x),$ so it will naturally come up as cosines

Comment: You can't: $(\sin{x})^6$ has sixth derivative $6!$ at $x=0$, but the sixth derivative of any linear combination of $\sin{nx}$ has sixth derivative zero (because it is odd).

Comment: You can get something in terms of sin(nx) for $(sinx)^k$ only if k is odd.